# Grails Migrations Plugin

Tags: database, grails, jenkins

I have an issue with the Grails Migrations plugin (version 1.3.2). I have a changelog setup of groovy files to run, however when I run "dbm-update" and the database is already populated, the command errors out FROM JENKINS. If I run the same command from my local machine, "dbm-update" just immediately finished because the database is already up-to-date.

From what I read and how I understand it to work, "dbm-update" should run any changesets that have not been run yet. I don't know why Jenkins would behave differently. And just to note, I'm using the grails wrapper to build on jenkins and I did test "dbm-update" with the grails wrapper on my local machine and it is working properly.

Comment: What is the error when you execute from Jenkins? Is dbm-update run with the same db environment?

Comment: Yes same db environment is used (AWS RDS Oracle). The error in Jenkins starts as: "Starting dbm-update for database xxxxxx@jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx.xxxx.com:1521:xxxx

Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure"

dbm-update never finishes and build fails.

Comment: Can you run dbm-update with --verbose?